# three.js - webgl ocean demo

Tags: three.js

If you are familiar with the examples for three.js - there is an an example called [webgl ocean demo](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_shaders_ocean)

I can't see the actual materials when I run it locally or when I change the paths to the local resources. Has anyone else resolved this problem? I want to experiment with a different image instead of the globe that is floating in the ocean.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - geometry - terrain</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                color: #000;
                font-family:Monospace;
                font-size:13px;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #info {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px; width: 100%;
                text-align:center;
                padding: 5px;
            }

            a {

                color: #a06851;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="info"><a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js</a> - webgl ocean demo</div>

        <script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Mirror.js"></script>
        <script src="js/WaterShader.js"></script>

        <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            if ( ! Detector.webgl ) {

                Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
                document.getElementById( 'container' ).innerHTML = "";

            }

            var container, stats;
            var camera, scene, renderer;
            var sphere;

            var parameters = {
                width: 2000,
                height: 2000,
                widthSegments: 250,
                heightSegments: 250,
                depth: 1500,
                param: 4,
                filterparam: 1
            };

            var waterNormals;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 55, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.5, 3000000 );
                camera.position.set( 2000, 750, 2000 );

                controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
                controls.enablePan = false;
                controls.minDistance = 1000.0;
                controls.maxDistance = 5000.0;
                controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI * 0.495;
                controls.center.set( 0, 500, 0 );

                scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x444444 ) );

                var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffbb, 1 );
                light.position.set( - 1, 1, - 1 );
                scene.add( light );


                waterNormals = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/waternormals.jpg' );
                waterNormals.wrapS = waterNormals.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

                water = new THREE.Water( renderer, camera, scene, {
                    textureWidth: 512,
                    textureHeight: 512,
                    waterNormals: waterNormals,
                    alpha:  1.0,
                    sunDirection: light.position.clone().normalize(),
                    sunColor: 0xffffff,
                    waterColor: 0x001e0f,
                    distortionScale: 50.0,
                } );


                mirrorMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
                    new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( parameters.width * 500, parameters.height * 500 ),
                    water.material
                );

                mirrorMesh.add( water );
                mirrorMesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI * 0.5;
                scene.add( mirrorMesh );


                // load skybox

                var cubeMap = new THREE.CubeTexture( [] );
                cubeMap.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

                var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader();
                loader.load( 'textures/skyboxsun25degtest.png', function ( image ) {

                    var getSide = function ( x, y ) {

                        var size = 1024;

                        var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
                        canvas.width = size;
                        canvas.height = size;

                        var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
                        context.drawImage( image, - x * size, - y * size );

                        return canvas;

                    };

                    cubeMap.images[ 0 ] = getSide( 2, 1 ); // px
                    cubeMap.images[ 1 ] = getSide( 0, 1 ); // nx
                    cubeMap.images[ 2 ] = getSide( 1, 0 ); // py
                    cubeMap.images[ 3 ] = getSide( 1, 2 ); // ny
                    cubeMap.images[ 4 ] = getSide( 1, 1 ); // pz
                    cubeMap.images[ 5 ] = getSide( 3, 1 ); // nz
                    cubeMap.needsUpdate = true;

                } );

                var cubeShader = THREE.ShaderLib[ 'cube' ];
                cubeShader.uniforms[ 'tCube' ].value = cubeMap;

                var skyBoxMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
                    fragmentShader: cubeShader.fragmentShader,
                    vertexShader: cubeShader.vertexShader,
                    uniforms: cubeShader.uniforms,
                    depthWrite: false,
                    side: THREE.BackSide
                } );

                var skyBox = new THREE.Mesh(
                    new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1000000, 1000000, 1000000 ),
                    skyBoxMaterial
                );

                scene.add( skyBox );


                var geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry( 400, 4 );

                for ( var i = 0, j = geometry.faces.length; i < j; i ++ ) {

                    geometry.faces[ i ].color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );

                }

                var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
                    vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,
                    shininess: 100,
                    envMap: cubeMap
                } );

                sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                scene.add( sphere );

            }

            //

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                render();

            }

            function render() {

                var time = performance.now() * 0.001;

                sphere.position.y = Math.sin( time ) * 500 + 250;
                sphere.rotation.x = time * 0.5;
                sphere.rotation.z = time * 0.51;

                water.material.uniforms.time.value += 1.0 / 60.0;
                controls.update();
                water.render();
                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my code - just changed the relative paths

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                color: #000;
                font-family:Monospace;
                font-size:13px;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #info {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px; width: 100%;
                text-align:center;
                padding: 5px;
            }

            a {

                color: #a06851;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="info"><a href="http://aaneok.org" target="_blank">AA</a> ocean demo</div>

        <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Mirror.js"></script>
        <script src="js/WaterShader.js"></script>

        <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            if ( ! Detector.webgl ) {

                Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
                document.getElementById( 'container' ).innerHTML = "";

            }

            var container, stats;
            var camera, scene, renderer;
            var sphere;

            var parameters = {
                width: 2000,
                height: 2000,
                widthSegments: 250,
                heightSegments: 250,
                depth: 1500,
                param: 4,
                filterparam: 1
            };

            var waterNormals;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 55, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.5, 3000000 );
                camera.position.set( 2000, 750, 2000 );

                controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
                controls.enablePan = false;
                controls.minDistance = 1000.0;
                controls.maxDistance = 5000.0;
                controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI * 0.495;
                controls.center.set( 0, 500, 0 );

                scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x444444 ) );

                var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffbb, 1 );
                light.position.set( - 1, 1, - 1 );
                scene.add( light );


                waterNormals = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'js/waternormals.jpg' );
                waterNormals.wrapS = waterNormals.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

                water = new THREE.Water( renderer, camera, scene, {
                    textureWidth: 512,
                    textureHeight: 512,
                    waterNormals: waterNormals,
                    alpha:  1.0,
                    sunDirection: light.position.clone().normalize(),
                    sunColor: 0xffffff,
                    waterColor: 0x001e0f,
                    distortionScale: 50.0,
                } );


                mirrorMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
                    new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( parameters.width * 500, parameters.height * 500 ),
                    water.material
                );

                mirrorMesh.add( water );
                mirrorMesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI * 0.5;
                scene.add( mirrorMesh );


                // load skybox

                var cubeMap = new THREE.CubeTexture( [] );
                cubeMap.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

                var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader();
                loader.load( 'js/skyboxsun25degtest.png', function ( image ) {

                    var getSide = function ( x, y ) {

                        var size = 1024;

                        var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
                        canvas.width = size;
                        canvas.height = size;

                        var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
                        context.drawImage( image, - x * size, - y * size );

                        return canvas;

                    };

                    cubeMap.images[ 0 ] = getSide( 2, 1 ); // px
                    cubeMap.images[ 1 ] = getSide( 0, 1 ); // nx
                    cubeMap.images[ 2 ] = getSide( 1, 0 ); // py
                    cubeMap.images[ 3 ] = getSide( 1, 2 ); // ny
                    cubeMap.images[ 4 ] = getSide( 1, 1 ); // pz
                    cubeMap.images[ 5 ] = getSide( 3, 1 ); // nz
                    cubeMap.needsUpdate = true;

                } );

                var cubeShader = THREE.ShaderLib[ 'cube' ];
                cubeShader.uniforms[ 'tCube' ].value = cubeMap;

                var skyBoxMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
                    fragmentShader: cubeShader.fragmentShader,
                    vertexShader: cubeShader.vertexShader,
                    uniforms: cubeShader.uniforms,
                    depthWrite: false,
                    side: THREE.BackSide
                } );

                var skyBox = new THREE.Mesh(
                    new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1000000, 1000000, 1000000 ),
                    skyBoxMaterial
                );

                scene.add( skyBox );


                var geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry( 400, 4 );

                for ( var i = 0, j = geometry.faces.length; i < j; i ++ ) {

                    geometry.faces[ i ].color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );

                }

                var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
                    vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,
                    shininess: 100,
                    envMap: cubeMap
                } );

                sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                scene.add( sphere );

            }

            //

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                render();

            }

            function render() {

                var time = performance.now() * 0.001;

                sphere.position.y = Math.sin( time ) * 500 + 250;
                sphere.rotation.x = time * 0.5;
                sphere.rotation.z = time * 0.51;

                water.material.uniforms.time.value += 1.0 / 60.0;
                controls.update();
                water.render();
                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check your browser's console, you'll see error messages regarding the local access of files: by default, modern browsers do not allow this. This problem isn't three.js related at all, it is a common browser security policy.

Basically, there are two workarounds:

- run a local server or put your code online
- modify the browser settings to allow local file access.

As a lot of people trying their hands on three.js run into this issue when loading textures, there is a [dedicated Three.js Wiki page](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally) on the topic.